# server error 500 when calling auth dialog for not authenticated before users

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, authentication, dialog

when i try to sign up a new user throw my app requesting the dialog url returns a 500 error page on "chrome windows " and blank in "firefox ubuntu"

## *Steps to Reproduce:*#

generate an auth url with
client_id,
redirect_uri
state,
scope

## *Expected Behavior:*

display the authentication dialogue to the user with the permission
then redirect to the callback url with parameters

## Actual Behavior#:

returns a 500 error page on "chrome windows " and blank in "firefox ubuntu"
link to test
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=228169977330896&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.jobzella.com%2Fsocialauth%2Fauth%2Fcallback%2Ffacebook&state=ba63140fdc0ed2d8b5e133a321966363&scope=offline_access%2Cemail%2Cuser_birthday&response_type=code

Comment: Turn on error reporting in your code... http://www.jorble.com/2012/06/how-to-display-php-error/

Comment: actually , everything is now working fine, facebook was having issues , and it was solved from there side

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with scope "offline_access" which is invalid.

Facebook does not give detail of error when scope is invalid, this has been observed by me.

Comment: actually , everything is now working fine, facebook was having issues , and it was was solved from they side